# Custom touch tracking in iphone

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

I don't want to use any of the normal touch events in the iphone sdk.

When an user touches the screen I want to find where he touched and all of pixels he touches. Is there a way to do it in iphone ? may be using a low level SDK.

i want this to do it for some thing like a  drawing app with finger on iphone.

Answer (score 2):

There is no low-level API. IIRC, the data in a touch object is actually returned by the hardware. In other words, that is all the data that software can get.

Having done some touch UI experiments in the distant past, I can tell you that processing real world touches in software is a lot more complicated than you would expect on first glance. It's not like tracking a mouse. A finger is actually a very blunt and imprecise pointing instrument on the scale of a mobil screen.  There is a great deal of variation in finger size, pressure of contact, contact area, angle of contact and consistency of contact. It takes a lot of processing to turn that blunt imprecision into a single point or collection of points that an API can easily use.

I wouldn't try to reinvent the wheel even if you find a way to extract more data from the hardware. If nothing else, (puts on interface-nazi hat) if your touch interface behaves different from other apps, users will be confused when the have to switch back and forth.

Comment: i understand that touch is not a imprecise gesture, But the idea i have requires that I get the touch area rather than a point. May be its not possible with the present API.

Answer (score 1):

A touch is a rather imprecise gesture, so getting all the pixels that one encompasses is not really possible. However, you can get the rough 'center' of a touch, and extrapolate an area around that for a group of 'touched pixels'. No need to use a low level SDK, just override -touchesBegan:withEvent: on UIView.