# Is it possible to get more low level info about touch events?

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

The UITouch object only gives you the location of the touch. Is it possible to find out about the size and the shape of the touch(the part of your finger that meets the screen) as well?

*Update: non-iphone info, but the Android API seems to give the [size](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getSize(int)).*

Comment: This question is very similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985468/custom-touch-tracking-in-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Not with the public APIs.